# These two commands are similar, is there any syntax error that i am making

Tags: python

```
m1 = A['Gender'] == 'Male'
m2 = A['Attrition'] == 'Yes'
A[m1 & m2]
```

The code above gives me the desired output of selecting Male employees who have left the company.
But the code below doesn't work. Can anyone tell me why

```
A[A['Gender']=='Male' &  A['Attrition']=='Yes']
```

Comment: Do you get a `SyntaxError` exception?

Comment: No, I get this Cannot perform 'rand_' with a dtyped [object] array and scalar of type [bool]

Comment: Then you are not making a syntax error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Be explicit about your expression's operator precedence with parentheses:

```
A[(A["Gender"] == "Male") & (A["Attrition"] == "Yes")]
```